# passenger with apache error "Could not download..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu, apache2, passenger, ruby-2.1

I'm use: `Ubuntu Ubuntu 15.04 x64, Ruby 2.1.4, Rails 4.2.3, Passenger 5.0.0.rc2 or later tryed,  Apache 2.4.10`.

I can't start project in production, because recieve the error:

```
[ 2015-08-24 10:40:53.2503 3427/7fc8ed450700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 1-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 952e5695. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 3829 stdout:
App 3829 stderr:  --> Compiling passenger_native_support.so for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 3829 stderr:
App 3829 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 3829 stderr:
App 3829 stderr:  --> Downloading precompiled passenger_native_support.so for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 3829 stderr:
App 3829 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 3829 stderr:
App 3829 stderr:      Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.0.0.rc2/rubyext-ruby-2.1.4-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
App 3829 stderr:      Trying next mirror...
App 3829 stderr:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.0.0.rc2/rubyext-ruby-2.1.4-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
App 3829 stderr:  --> Continuing without passenger_native_support.so.
App 3829 stdout:
[ 2015-08-24 12:00:43.5322 3427/7fc8f3c99700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/html/apptest: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: cddc003b
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-V7RWyB.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-5.0.0.rc2/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:278:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-5.0.0.rc2/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:381:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-5.0.0.rc2/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:276:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-5.0.0.rc2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-5.0.0.rc2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:157:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-5.0.0.rc2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-5.0.0.rc2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "could not download" is not the actual issue here. As you can see, it later said "Continuing without passenger_native_support", meaning that it falled back to a mechanism that didn't require downloading anything. The *actual* issue is what came after that: "cannot load such file -- bundler/setup". That probably means your app is being run as the wrong user. Check the error details dump at /tmp/passenger-error-V7RWyB.html and double check whether all the settings are correct. In particular, double check whether the user is correct, and read on [Passenger's user account sandboxing](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/user_sandboxing.html) to learn how to fix that.